# How to get manual of read command of shell by man read?

Tags: shell

I would like to read a manual of read command of shell.
 I tried

```
man read
```

And I got a manual of read but it is a manual of read of C language.
 How to get manual of read of shell? Thank you very much.

Comment: `man bash` search for read.

Comment: @PS. : Thank you for telling me where the manual of read command is.